# mod_suexec ignored by php

Tags: php, apache, apache2, suexec

I set up a virtual host that uses `mod_suexec` to run PHP scripts as a different user than `www-data`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.server.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/my-site
    SuexecUserGroup webconfig webconfig
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I create a directory or a file (`mkdir`, `file_put_contents`), those files/dirs have `www-data` as an **owner**. I also can not read files that are only readable by `webconfig`.

I also noticed this strange behaviour: This php file:

```
echo get_current_user()."\n";
echo `whoami`."\n";
echo exec('whoami')."\n";
```

produces the following output:

```
webconfig
www-data
www-data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod_php5` is actually incompatible with `mod_suexec`. As described [in this article](http://www.alain.knaff.lu/howto/PhpSuexec/), you have to use `mod_suphp` and `php-cgi` instead. The downside is that this decreases performance.

A simple solution that works for Ubuntu is

```
apt-get install -y suphp-common, libapache2-mod-suphp
a2dismod php5
a2enmod suphp
```

The linked article describes how to use `mod_php5` for some vhosts and `mod_suphp` for others.